# prepare a wall for plumber and piping

Tags: plumbing, drywall

I'm getting a plumber to put in a toilet in a new location. He will need to run water pipes etc. So I assume the drywall has to come off in the area where pipes will go. However before the toilet is connected permanently, the drywall needs to be replaced/repaired.

I wonder if there is a smarter way of doing things than breaking/fixing drywall on the spot. Perhaps I could cut out a piece of the drywall in advance and replace with plywood on hinges to make a "door"? The edge would need to be covered with some sort of a trim.

The new location is on the other side of the wall from the current location, only a meter away.

Comment: It's not just the wall that will be damaged but the floor might have to get ripped up a bit as well depending on how the plumbing it is configured. You should speak with your plumber about this and just ask "Is there anything I can do in preparation for this project?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon for folks to install "access hatches" in areas that commonly have problems (e.g. shower valves) but I don't see any reason for access in the spot you reference. The in-wall plumbing for your new toilet is no different than all the other plumbing in your walls that is covered up with drywall.

Access hatches are always visible (and not usually pleasing aesthetically) and creating one is more work than just repairing the drywall. I don't see the point.

Comment: Are there also fire control issues with creating a hatch?  Drywall is sometimes used as a component in reducing the spread of fire.